# Find a function with certain properties.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a function $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$, $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq1$, and $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

I've tried cojoining two quarters of a circle to get an S-shaped graph of the function and tried with different combinations of $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ but so far nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Not allowed to use integrals

Answer (score 3):

Try
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & x\leq 1\\
C\int_0^x \exp\left(\frac{r}{t(t-1)}\right)\,dt,& 0<x<1 \\
1, &x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
for $r>0$. What is $C$?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not yet allowed to use integrals :/

Answer (score 1):

Try the function

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
\frac{1}{1+\exp(-g(x))} & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
1 & 1 < x
\end{cases}
$$
where $g(x)= (1-x)^{-1} - x^{-1}$.

Here's a [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvgcxqyztb) to Desmos where you can try it out.